# How to make a HTTP persistent connection using Volley library

Tags: android, android-volley

Hi can anyone please help in making a HTTP Live connection using Volley library.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean staying connected to an InputStream and react to partial results arriving progressively then it's not possible with Volley since Volley is designed to return the full response of a request in one batch as a byte array.

However if you mean performing multiple HTTP requests over a single TCP connection, then you have nothing to do; HTTP keepalive connections are handled automatically for you by the underlying HttpUrlConnection implementation.

Comment: Is there a library that supports performing the first task?

Comment: Yes, you can use OkHttp Web Sockets implementation: https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/okhttp-ws